# How can I only get the entries that are related to an active category

Tags: entries, categories, status

In the product overviews and search results on my website are also products listed which are related to passive categories.
Is there a way to get only entries which are related to active categories?
[image: The product with this category status should not be displayed at the website]

The product with this category status should not be displayed at the website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would first query for all active categories and then get the Product entries that are related to these categories.

```
{% set allCategories = craft.categories.group('Categorie') %}
{% set entriesWithActiveCategories = craft.entries.section('Products').relatedTo(allCategories) %}
```